# MongoDB: How to fetch the First document from the JSON array

Tags: json, mongodb

> db.tanmayResume.find({},{"Education":{$slice:1},Education:1,_id:0}).pretty()
>   {
>                  "Education" : 
>       [
>                               {
>                                           "University" : "State University of New York",
>                                           "Degree" : "Master of Science",
>                               },
>                               {
>                                           "University" : "University of Mumbai",
>                                           "Degree" : "Bachelor of Engineering",
>                            },
>                    ]
>               }
>           
>   How can I get the following output:
>       {
>           "University" : "State University of New York",
>           "Degree" : "Master of Science",
>       }

Comment: can you show us your document structure?

Comment: It is similar to this<br/>{
    "name":"John",
    "age":30,
    "cars": [
        { "name":"Ford", "model": "Fiesta" },
        { "name":"BMW", "models": "X3" },
        { "name":"Fiat", "models":"500" }
    ]
 }

Comment: Education is basically an array with embedded documents containing 'Univerisity' and Degree fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

`db.getCollection('things').aggregate([{$unwind:"$Education"},
{$limit:1},
{ $project : { Education : 1 } }])`

Comment: @vignesg is this correct: 'db.Resume.aggregate([{$unwind:"$Education"},{$limit:1}]).pretty()'
Because It's returns the whole document.

Comment: which version of mongodb are you using

Comment: I am using mongodb 3.4.16

Comment: can you give the db.find() output because i miss understood `{
      "Education" : 
      [
        {
                 "University" : "State University of New York",
                 "Degree" : "Master of Science",
        },
        {
                 "University" : "University of Mumbai",
                 "Degree" : "Bachelor of Engineering",
        },
    ]
}` as input

Comment: get me the response for db.tanmayResume.find({})

Comment: {
      "_id" : 1,
      "Name" : "xxx",
      "Searchtype": "xxxxx",
      "Email":
      [
        {
          "type": "primary",
          "Address": "xxx@gmail.com"
        },
        {
          "type": "secondary",
          "Address": "xxx@binghamton.edu"
        }
      ],
      "Education":
      [
        {
          "University":"State University of New York",
          "Degree": "Master of Science",
        },
        {
          "University":"University of Mumbai",
          "Degree": "Bachelor of Engineering",
        }
      ]
}

Comment: try using this buddy `db.Resume.aggregate([{$unwind:"$Education"},
{$limit:1},
{ $project : { Education : 1 } }])`

Comment: Got it Thank you bro.

Comment: ok great to hear from you hope you will ask more querions like this ..and do upvote my answer and close this buddy

Comment: click on the up arrow for upvoting the answeer